# Error with child process & wait `C`

Tags: c, fork, wait

In the below code, if there is a problem creating a child process or something happens to the child process what happens to `wait(&status)`?

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
if(pid=fork()){
   printf("Parent Process\n");
   wait(&status);
} else... child process here
```

Comment: There's a problem with your syntax. Your `pid` will only ever be `0` or `1`.

Comment: How does that look @KerrekSB

Comment: Better, but you can't handle errors now. I'd just go with `int status; pid_t pid = fork(); if (pid < 0) { /* error */ } else if (pid > 0) { waitpid(pid, &status, 0); } else { /* child */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child cannot be created, fork() will return with -1, you should look at errno after that. No error process is created here. Your code does not check this case.

If the child is created and dies, wait() will return the PID of the terminated process, the reason for the child's death is given in status. See the  [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for wait on how to extract meaning from status.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a problem creating a child process, fork will return `-1`, so this code will never `wait`.

If there's something happend to the child process, wait will return, and you can observe `status`.

Comment: Probably should have put this in the question, what if I have created 2 child processes? @Karoly Horvath

Comment: From the manual: "The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates."